# Matching regex pattern in Array of Strings

Tags: regex, scala

I have a following snapshot of a long String array:

```
Array[String] = Array("Tony Stark (USA) 16th October 2015", "Peter Comb (Canada) 21st September 2015")
```

I expect to have output as:

```
Array[String] = Array("Tony Stark", "Peter Comb")    
Array[String] = Array("USA", "Canada")
Array[String] = Array("16th October 2015", "21st September 2015")
```

I have tried this:

```
"[.]+\\(([.]+)\\)[.]+"
```

But it is unable to parse. What could be the regex pattern to parse my RDD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your regex is that inside the `[]`, `.` is a literal `.` not a wildcard.

You're also missing groups around the name and the dates. The correct regex would be `(.+)\\((.+)\\)(.+)`.

Calling the array `a` and the regex `r`, this gives:

```
scala> a.map {case r(name, country,year) => (name, country, year)}
res4: Array[(String, String, String)] = Array(("Tony Stark ",USA," 16th October 2015"), ("Peter Comb ",Canada," 21st September 2015"))
```

Presumably you'd want to match the spaces as well so they don't get pulled out in the groups.

Comment: @holyland thanks it worked, while discovering new cases, i found that <(country)> is an option. That is, also exist cases such as "Claudio Stallone 18th September 2009"
I tried to extend the above case like this:

User_Info.map { 
     | case pattern(name, country, year) => (name, country, year)
     | case _ => (name, "", year)}

But it gives me : missing argument list for method year in object functions
Unapplied methods are only converted to functions when a function type is expected.

Answer (score 2):

```
val rdd: Array[String] = Array ("Tony Stark (USA) 16th October 2015", "Peter Comb (Canada) 21st September 2015")
(0 to 2).map (i => rdd.map (_.split ("[\\)\\(]")).map (a=> a(i)))
Vector(Array("Tony Stark ", "Peter Comb "), Array(USA, Canada), Array(" 16th October 2015", " 21st September 2015"))
```

A final trim cleans up the whitespace:

```
(0 to 2).map (i => rdd.map (_.split ("[\\)\\(]")).map (a=> a(i).trim))
Vector(Array(Tony Stark, Peter Comb), Array(USA, Canada), Array(16th October 2015, 21st September 2015))
```

Now to the regex:

```
"[.]+\\(([.]+)\\)[.]+"
```

A character group of one character makes rarely much sense - [a]+ is the same as a+. But for the dot it is different, it makes the dot a literal dot, since a dot as joker in a group doesn't make sense, it is just .+ .

While your sample text doesn't contain any literal dot, nor multiple in consecutive form, I guess it was just meant as .+

```
".+\\((.+)\\).+"
```

But regexes can be used in multiple ways. s.replace, s.matches, s.split and so on. Without information how you used it, it doesn't allow further reasoning.